# Create a Wit.ai conversation flow

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai

How can I create a flow with wit.ai, the documentation says to use the Stories tab, but don't show in my dashboard (and I trying to create a Portuguese bot)
Tks

Comment: Wit has deprecated the Stories Ui, you will have to build the flow on your end.

Comment: More info here: https://wit.ai/blog/2017/07/27/sunsetting-stories

Comment: And here: https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-stories-migration-tutorial